# Can we connect to elasticsearch cluster from Azure website?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, web

I am trying to use elasticsearch for search functionality in my website. I have setup elasticsearch in my local development environment and it works fine.

1. I have setup the elasticsearch on Ubuntu Linux machine as given [here](http://code972.com/blog/2014/07/74-the-definitive-guide-for-elasticsearch-on-windows-azure)
2. I have opened endpoints (ports) 9200 and 9300 on the Linux elasticsearch server.
3. I have created a virtual network and my website and this elasticsearch server are in the same virtual network.

I am able to connect to my Linux elasticsearch server from my local machine using a public IP.

I could not connect to Linux elasticsearch server from my Azure website either from internal IP like 10.0.0.4 and configured public IP.

I want to check whether connecting to elasticsearch port 9200 from Azure website is possible or not? Also please suggest a way to check existing configuration to troubleshoot the Azure website to elasticsearch connectivity issue.

Comment: If you can connect ES from home (with public IP), then the problem is only in Azure. Open the firewall (set security groups) properly should fix the access issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. We do it for audit logging and event logging from both azure websites and cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

In the above article I mentioned, it says it is not possible, I tried but could not connect. There is something called hybrid connection but that can be setup only for windows servers. Here is the line that is mentioned in this article

http://code972.com/blog/2014/07/74-the-definitive-guide-for-elasticsearch-on-windows-azure

"Unfrotunately, Azure Websites do not currently support running on a Virtual Network, meaning you can only deploy websites as a Cloud Service if you want them to access the cluster this way."

I checked few more blog posts and found such comments. So, I have given up using Linux server and taken a Windows 2012R2 searver, configured elasticsearch and was able to access elasticsearch cluster now.

If anybody has a solid information on how to connect Azure website to Linux VM please give me links or steps.